# How to use same button for different actions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so I'm building a platformer with two types of jump. 
Normal jump - whilst on ground, pressing space bar
Air jump - whilst jumping, a limited amount of extra jumps (also whilst pressing space bar)

I've worked out the main mechanics for this jump, But I've hit a snag. the limited amount of airjumps starts as 3 each time you jump. However, with the code I've written, Unity is using the initial "normal jump" as one of the three.

Here is a sample of my code below:

```
bool pressingJumpButton = Input.GetKeyDown("space");
    if (pressingJumpButton)
    {

        if (canJump)
        {
            jumping = true;
        }
    }       

if (jumping)
{

    if (pressingJumpButton && inAir == false) {
       Debug.Log("jump");
       GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(
       GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x,
       jumpingSpeed,
       GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z);

       inAir = true;

     }
}
//airJump logic
if(inAir==true)
{
   airJump = true;

   if (airJump && maxAir>0 && pressingJumpButton)
   {
       Debug.Log("airJump");
       maxAir -= 1;
       GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(
       GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x,
       jumpingSpeed,
       GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z);
   }
}

// on the floor
void OnTriggerStay (Collider otherCollider)
{
    if (otherCollider.tag =="JumpingArea")
    {

        canJump = true;
        jumping = false;
        inAir = false;
        maxAir = 3;
        airJump = false;

    }
}
```

I put the debug.logs in to see if I could find the issue and when I'm doing the first jump (from the ground) its registering as both normal and air jumps.

I thought that by having an inAir bool that only returns true after pressing the jump button once would be the fix but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you change `pressingJumpButton` value?

Comment: "with the code I've written, Unity is using the initial "normal jump" as one of the three" - if that really is the cause, then why not just change `maxAir` to `maxJumps` and increase it to 4? That would save you implementing logic to work out if you're on the first jump or not.

Comment: hi Ant, I thought about that, but the airJump variable will be upgradable in the game and I thought that it may cause me more issues later down the line if I don't separate it.

Comment: I've added my pressingJumpButton code to the OP

Comment: If i got it correctly, when you press space you make the bool true. And you are on the ground so you get the "jump" log. But now you are in the air but bool is still true. So you get "airJump" log.

Comment: That's right, but when you are on the ground, you shouldn't get the airJump log as I'm using an if(inAir) statement - however that's not what's happening in reality

Comment: If this part of code runs in `Update()` , you will get both logs because of the reason I said earlier.

Comment: Ah ok, so how do I fix it? I've tried to move this section of code outside of Update{} but it has given me compiler errors everywhere.
Sorry for the noob questions, this is my first project outside of tutorials

Comment: Solution below thanks to Colin and anyone else who knows basic if/else statements - D'oh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine your jumping and in air test and use an `else` clause. As it's written, you are doing the jump, setting `inAir = true` and then after that testing if `inAir` is true, meaning you are always doing an air jump after every normal jump.

```
if (jumping && !inAir)
{
  Debug.Log("jump");
  ...
}
else if (inAir && jumping)
{
  Debug.Log("airJump");
  ...
}
```

There is also no need to recheck `pressingJumpButton` since you've already tested that when setting `jumping = true`.

A (IMHO) better version that avoids repeated code and gets rid of unnecessary variables:

```
if (pressingJumpButton && canJump)
{
    if (!inAir)
    {
        Debug.Log("jump");
        inAir = true;
        DoJump();
    }
    else if (maxAir > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("airJump");
        maxAir--;
        DoJump();
    }

}
private void DoJump()
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = 
        new Vector3(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x, 
                    jumpingSpeed, 
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z);
}
```

Comment: BOOM! Colin! You are the man.

I'm also slightly annoyed with myself, as it seems obvious now.

Thank you

Comment: When I'm faced with debugging a set of logic that isn't behaving as expected I'll often fall back to drawing an old-school flowchart -- on paper. It cuts through all the clutter of unrelated code text and shows exactly how things flow. I also made a small edit -- there was a missing test in the else.

Comment: Yeah the flow chart makes a lot of sense. I will use your wisdom, Guru. 

I managed to get it working just by adding else to my code, but I want to streamline as much as possible so I will use your code and see if that works for me.

Comment: I added (&& maxAir>0) in the first if statement otherwise it allowed for infinite jumps, but other than that it works perfectly. Thanks again